# Аналоги BitrixMobile под Android

Tags: android, java

Подскажите аналоги данного фреймворка под Android. 
[BitrixMobile](http://www.1c-bitrix.ru/products/cms/features/bitrixmobile.php)

Может кто сталкивался, работал.

Интересует именно создание мобильных сайтов под Андроид. 
PhoneGap тоже ведь подходит по идеи, верно?

**UPD**

Интересует что-то вроде CMS-ки или типового функционала для мобильного сайта, который может быть легко использован для типовых задач.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сайт для телефонов - это обычный сайт с кастомным видом для отображения на мобильных девайсах. Многие цмски предоставляют такой функционал (встроенный или как плагин), например, вордПрес, ну или даже в студии есть такая возможность.

ФонеГап - это фреймворк, для мобильный приложений в общем, но если разрабатывать на нем мобильный-клиент для сайта, который легко можно будет портировать на любую мобильную ОС  -идея неплохая.

Comment: обновил вопрос. А то что обычный сайт он же и сайт для телефона я прекрасно понимаю:)

Comment: ну я видел в студии как работает такие фокусы для создания сайтов на асп.нэт, видел на шарпоинте - там автоматически генерится вьюха для мобильных, видел в вордПресе, я думаю тебе может подойти тот-же dreamweaver, надо же конструктор и какойто механизм, который будет отличать устройство на котором светится сайт

Comment: по сути вопрос уже не актуален. БитриксМобайл - это обертка вокруг JQuery Mobile и PhoneGap. Они сами это потвердили. Проблема в том, что нет ничего типового в плане функциональности как у этих ребят. У них уже есть инет-магазин адаптированный под это дело. И портал кажись.

Comment: Вопрос закрывать не нужно было, ибо альтернативы не найдено.